# Android Emulator always crashes

Tags: android-emulator

I'm a newbie trying to learn React Native.
My Android Studio emulator crashes every now and then, and I need to restart my PC to use it again (to kill the qemu-system-x86_64.exe doesn't work)

I expanded the memory 16gb internal storage (now I try to 32gb and 8gb)  but nothing really improved.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the output of the log window.

Comment: I have no output just crashes
with the last updates lately way less